# HTTP Get not working on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get

I'm working on an application where I have a client in Angular and my server is in C. I have a problem with my HTTP Get but I can't find it. "updateStream()" is called every 70 ms.

```
public updateStream(): void {
   if (this.isVideoRunning && this.canChangePicture) {
     console.log('put is called');
     this.putData();
   }
}

public getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get('http://IP_ADRESS:3490/testStream', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
}

public putData(): void {
   console.log('put function');
   this.canChangePicture = false;
   let comp: number;
   this.getData().subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      const responseArray: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(resp);
      const newTabTemp: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4);
      comp = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4; i = i + 4) {
         newTabTemp[i] = responseArray[comp];
         newTabTemp[i + 1] = responseArray[comp];
         newTabTemp[i + 2] = responseArray[comp];
         newTabTemp[i + 3] = 255;
         comp = comp + 1;
     }

  let nouvData: ImageData;
  nouvData = new ImageData(newTabTemp, this.maxWidth, this.maxHeight);
  this.contextVideo.putImageData(nouvData, BORDERX / 2, BORDERY / 2);
  this.canChangePicture = true;
  });
}
```

My problem was that my canvas would almost never change so I tried to put some "console.log" and I discovered that the problem is somehow my program would not enter in "this.getData().subscribe()..." after a few request.

[image: Those are my console.log]

As you can see my program keep entering "putData()" but not the "this.getData().subscribe()...". What is wrong with my code and how I fix it?

EDIT:

Screenshot of the pending request
[image: Pending request]
timing tab: [image: Timing tab]
Request/response
[image]

Comment: What if you open up the network tab in chrome's dev tools? Can you see your requests there? Maybe with a pending status?

Comment: @David Yes they're a lot of requests that are pending. What does that mean?

Comment: AFAIK, chrome can only handle 6 active connections at the same time. After that, subsequent requests are left pending.

Comment: @David As you can see, I edited my answer to add a boolean. Now the problem is for some reason I always have one request whose stuck in pending. Why is it pending?

Comment: Is is not because you still have active connections from your previous tests? Go there and try closing/flushing sockets chrome://net-internals/#sockets

Comment: @David I did that, it worked for 1 minute and then back to pending.

Comment: It's hard to tell just like that. Maybe try reproducing it on stackblitz (not necessarily with an image)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on a request in the network tab and see why it is Pending.

If it is stalled, then Chrome has queued it. Learn more [about stalling and how to resolve it](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/issues)

If its server that is not responding, then you need to check the backend.

If requirements permit, updateStream() may be called after the previous one has completed.

If requirements permit, you may even opt for Websockets or SSE for faster communication than HTTP methods.

Comment: Can you help me understand what is happening plz? I edited the questions to add  a screen shot of the pending request

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the timing tab too.

Comment: As you see Chrome  is stalling the request. There is link 'Explannation' in the timing tab to help you with details. You are sending requests too fast.

Comment: I looked at it before and I made sure there is an extra 15-20ms before every new request. That's why I don't understand why the request is waiting for anything. There is no request possible as long as the canChangePicture is not true again.

Comment: Hmmm. I am guessing that canChangePicture  is not set to true anywhere else. I  would put 'let self = this;' after let comp statement. And in the subscribe function use self.canChangePicture  =true; This is for scoping. I am not sure it is the explanation.

Comment: try closing and flushing the sockets again. Check other requests in the network tab have also completed.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 console.log

1. updateStream function ,`console.log('put is called');`
2. putData function , `console.log('put function')`
3. console.log(resp) inside    the `getData.Subscribe()`

In your console.log I can see your:

```
Observable <ArrayBuffer>
```

response of your HttpClient  , that's meant that you make the request/response.

Can you show this response in Cromme Dev Tools?

Comment: This time it only worked once. I edited the answer with a screenshot